# Getting CodeMirror value from an object function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, object, codemirror

I have the following code:

```
 var examples = {
    'style': {
        create: function (div, ref) {
            var codeMirror = CodeMirror(div, {
                lineNumbers: true,
                mode: 'css'
            });

            this.firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror(ref, codeMirror);

            var self = this;
            this.firepad.on('ready', function () {
                if (self.firepad.isHistoryEmpty()) {
                    self.firepad.setText('.red {color: red;}');
                }
            });
        },
        dispose: function () {
            this.firepad.dispose();
        }
    }
};
```

Now usually I would go `codeMirror.getValue()` to get the contents of the CodeMirror instance unfortuantely I have no idea how to access a variable in a function in a object (have I even said that right?)

I tried `examples.style.getValue()` but that of course returns an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't. Local variables cannot be accessed outside the function.

You'd have to use the [Firepad API](http://www.firepad.io/docs/#api) to get the value:

```
var text = examples.style.firepad.getText();
// or
var html = examples.style.firepad.getHtml();
```

Alternatively you can assign the CodeMirror instance to a property and use `getValue`.

However you probably want to add another method to the object, for convenience:

```
getText: function() {
  return this.firepad.getText();
}
```

Comment: Trying this receiving error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined'

Comment: Of course you need to have `examples.style.create();` called beforehand.

Comment: I have an initialize function that is creating the CodeMirror instance, I am running the ``getText()`` later on, will this break it?

Comment: Note sure what *"I am running the getText() later on"* is supposed to imply. What I posted will work with the information you provided. I can't help you further if you don't provide a complete example.

Comment: Sorry here is the code as a gist, bear in mind it has pretty much been copied pasted out of firepad I am well aware of how under-optimised it is:
https://gist.github.com/CrashyBang/495ffcee365d54deba41

Comment: You *are* calling `getText` *before* `create`. If you set breakpoints (e.g. via `debugger;`) will notice that the last two lines execute before any of the event handlers.

Comment: Felix can you see anything in that code that would mean the getText function would not work on the script and structure objects?